# What is the NamedRouteQuery for 'index' actions in Batman.js

Tags: javascript, batman.js

I am trying to redirect to an index action after save, and can't figure out the proper NamedRouteQuery. I have tried:

- `@routes.posts.index`
- `App.get('routes.posts.index')
- `App.get('routes.posts').index
- `App.get('routes.posts')
- `App.get('routes').posts

etc, but in the end the only thing that works is `@redirect '/posts'`. Is the string version the only option for `index` actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to get this done.

#### Passing params to `Batman.redirect`

Calling `@redirect` handles the controller before/afterActions, then delegates to `Batman.redirect`.`Batman.redirect` can take:

- a string, which is treated as the target URL (`"/posts"`)
- a Batman.Model, which redirects to the index (`Batman.redirect(MyApp.Post)` redirects to `"/posts"`)
- a Batman.Model instance, which redirects to "show" (`Batman.redirect(thisPost)` redirects to `"/posts/#{thisPost.id}"`*)
- an object containing params:

  - `Batman.redirect({controller: "posts", action: "index"})` => `/posts`
  - `Batman.redirect({controller: "posts", action: "edit", id: 6})` => `/posts/6/edit`

** Actually calls `record.toParam?() || record.get('id')` to get the param*

**So,** you could use `@redirect({controller: "posts", action: "index"})` or `@redirect(App.Post)` to redirect to the index action.

#### Using a NamedRouteQuery

I'm not great with NamedRouteQuery, but here are some examples anyways:

- `App.get('routes').posts().path()` => `/posts`
- `App.get('routes').posts(6).path()` => `/posts/6`
- `App.get('routes').posts().get(6).path()` => `/posts/6`
- `App.get('routes').posts().get(6).get('edit').path()` => `/posts/6/edit`

You could use one of those to get your url string, then pass the string to `@redirect`.

Hope this helps!